# How to detect if one tweet agrees with another

Tags: computational-linguistics, sentiment-analysis

I want to detect tweet text agreement. Suppose someone posts some subjective opinion in twitter. Other users will post reply either agreeing or opposing the original tweet. I want to estimate the amount of agreement. Is there any algorithm/library to do that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this can't even be done by people.

Comment: What kind of breadth are you looking for in answers? Are you looking for tools that will analyze agreement for you, or are you talking about the broad fields of textual entailment, opinion mining, sentiment analysis, etc.?

Comment: @prash, no, I am only looking for some algorithm/tool that given two strings, will detect if and how much the second string is in agreement with the first one.